# How to find the avg of better films rating in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table 
Films

```
id  release_year    category_id rating
1   2015                 1         8
2   2015                 2        8.5
3   2015                 3         9
4   2016                 2        8.2
5   2016                 1        8.4
6   2017                 2         7
```

I want to add a new column "avg_better_films" to find an average rating of all better films in its release year

the output should be

```
id  release_year    category_id rating  avg_better_films
1   2015                1         8          8.75
2   2015                2        8.5           9
3   2015                3         9        Not Available
4   2016                2        8.2          8.4
5   2016                1        8.4       Not Available
6   2017                2         7        Not Available
```

and you can see, when the film has the best rating in the release year
it will show "Not Available"

Do you know how to get this output in MySQL

Comment: Easy way: correlated subquery.

Comment: Please dont use images; Formatted code text is better. I have rollbacked to previous "OK" version of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We can use a [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html) to calculate the Average rating for the "better films" for the same year.
- Subquery would return `null` in case of no better films for a specific film and year.
- We can then use [`Coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function to handle the case when there is no "better film" found for the year.
- Thanks to *@Strawberry* in comments, we need to do `+ 0` to the result of subquery, so that MySQL considers it as number

Try the following:

```
SELECT
  t1.id, 
  t1.release_year, 
  t1.category_id, 
  t1.rating, 
  COALESCE(
           (
            SELECT AVG(t2.rating) 
            FROM Films AS t2
            WHERE t2.rating > t1.rating AND  -- higher rating films
                  t2.release_year = t1.release_year -- films from same year
           ) + 0, 
           'Not Available' -- handle null result of subquery
          ) AS avg_better_films
FROM Films AS t1
```

**SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4960ea/3

Comment: Hi Madhur, the "avg_better_films" for each film is the avg of the films which have a better rating than it. If there are two better films, it should calculate the avg of the two films. If there is just one better film, it should just show the better film's rating.  I believe correlated subquery is the way to work, but I don't how to calculate the better avg for each film differently

Comment: @Rlearn my query is doing the same. It is calculating it for every film only. if there are better films in the same year, then it calculates average of ratings; otherwise return `Not Available`

Comment: @Strawberry thanks. Just curious that isn't `Avg()` function supposed to return either a number or `null`. What am I missing here ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I'm not sure I follow. If you're asking why I added '+0', it's because there's an implicit string casting (either in your query, or [more likely] in sqlfiddle's interpretation of your query). Adding +0 impicity casts it back again. To see what I mean, just try it without the +0

Comment: @Strawberry yeah; I tried without + 0, and that is why I am curious why the result of `Avg()` function got interpreted as string.

Comment: @Strawberry check this (DB fiddle's output): https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f1zXwqAzvwjGT8CTFw6wE6/0
It is being treated as "buffer". It is definitely a MySQL specific behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using scalar subquery

```
select *, (select avg(rating) from Films b on a.release_year=b.release_year) as avg_film_Rating
from Films a
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, because you need to output the results as a *string*, not a number.  If any value is a string, all must be.

I would recommend a correlated subquery that looks like:

```
SELECT f.*,
       (SELECT COALESCE(FORMAT(AVG(t2.rating), 2), 'Not Available)
            FROM Films f2
            WHERE f2.rating > f.rating AND 
                  f2.release_year = f.release_year
       ) AS avg_better_films
FROM Films f
```

Notes:

- Table aliases should be abbreviations for the table name.
- If no rows match the `WHERE` clause in the subquery, then `AVG()` returns `NULL`.  Hence, the `COALESCE()`can be in the subquery.
- `FORMAT()` is used to convert the average rating to a string.